# Preencher div com resultado ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

Tenho um pedido ajax com o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
    function AddVoto()
    {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{url('votos/adicionar/')}}/{{{$postagem->id_postagem}}}",
        data: {'id_post':<?php echo $postagem->id_postagem;?>, '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
           alert("pedido feito com sucesso");// apresentar aqui o resultado
        }
        });
    }
</script>

<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" id="myVoto" onclick="AddVoto();return false;">Adicionar voto</a>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

O pedido está a chegar correctamente, e quero imprimir o resultado do na div "resultado" mas não estou a conseguir. Como posso alterar o conteudo da div com o resultado do pedido ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a tua função retornar código HTML basta enviares o mesmo para a `div`, no teu *success*:

```
success: function(data){
           $("#resultado").html(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

O que você deve fazer é pegar o data e colocar dentro da `div`. não sei como que esta o seu objeto de retorno. Se for apenas um texto, só colocar o `data` mesmo dentro da div que nem o código abaixo.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#myVoto').click(function(){ AddVoto(); return false; });

            function AddVoto()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{url('votos/adicionar/')}}/{{{$postagem->id_postagem}}}",
                    data: {
                        'id_post':<?= $postagem->id_postagem ?>, 
                        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val()
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#resultado').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>

        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;" id="myVoto" onclick="AddVoto();return false;">Adicionar voto</a>

        <div id="resultado"></div>
```